# Request.Cookies["cookieName"] is null in web service method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, cookies

This is how I'am saving cookie in my code which is a web service method. I tried to change the cookie expire time but still it is not working for me. Is there any issue with `Context.Response` to write cookie or `Context.Request` to read it??

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public void SaveInDraft(FormRootObject _forms)
{
    HttpCookie formCookie = new HttpCookie("UserData");

    formCookie.Values.Add("formid", _forms.formid);

    foreach (var item in _forms.fielddata)
    {
        formCookie.Values.Add(item.id, item.value);
    }

    formCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    Context.Response.Cookies.Add(formCookie);

}
```

for retrieving this cookie on next page

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public FormRootObject getDataFromCookie()
{
    FormRootObject form = new FormRootObject();
    List<formFielddata> lstFormFieldData = new List<formFielddata>();

    var getCookie=Context.Request.Cookies["UserData"];
    if (getCookie != null)
    {
        if (getCookie.Values.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var val in getCookie.Values)
            {
                formFielddata document = new formFielddata();

                if (val.ToString() != "formid")
                {
                    document.id = val.ToString();
                    document.value = getCookie[val.ToString()];
                    lstFormFieldData.Add(document);
                }
                else {
                    form.formid = getCookie[val.ToString()];
                }
            }

            form.fielddata = lstFormFieldData;
        }
    }

    return form;
}
```

but my object `getCookie` is always `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this by storing cookies as

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(formCookie);
```

And reading this as

```
var getCookie=HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserData"];
```

Comment: though this worked for me but as my requirements user should be able to store cookie and retrieve those back without internet connectivity it is better to save cookie using javascript .[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh, forms are only present on web applications. If you're using plain web api to create your service, no form is going to be presented to your service client.

To create a cookie:
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();

```
var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", "12345");
cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
cookie.Path = "/";

resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
return resp;
```

To consume cookie:

```
CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("session-id")
```

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Comment: No i'm not using web api for this. it is .asmx  web service and 'forms' here is my class object